# Comparing collections with mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, optimization

I have about 25k documents in a collection (codename 'Parties') which is structured like this:

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("..."),
  "name": "Magic Show",
  "funStuff": [
    {
      "date": new Date("2010-01-04T16:00:00+1100"),
      "start": 5,
      "finish": 5.5,
      "symbol": "ABCD"
    }, ...
  ]
}, ...
```

Each document has a child array called funStuff that contains roughly 11k items.

I need to compare all Parties.funStuff using the date as a match.  For example:

1. Get 2 random documents (x, y) from parties
2. Map through x.funStuff and attempt to match a date with y.funStuff
3. If match occurs update/upsert a new document ('PartiesCompared') that looks roughly like this:

`{ parent: x._id, child: y.id, results: ... }`
4. Go back to step 2 moving forward a day.

I've tried a few JS solutions find -> map -> save results, but it very slow and will take months(just under a year lol) to complete. I'm obviously doing it very wrong.

Comment: this might be worth looking into: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9240636/how-to-compare-2-mongodb-collections